# Restoring Ubuntu System

Tags: 12.04, backup, restore

I had messed up my system running Ubuntu and Windows 7 and Windows 8.
I was not able to boot into Ubuntu while I was could boot into windows.
So I uninstalled Ubuntu through a live USB ,but before that i backed up the User folder,Now i have re installed Ubuntu , Is there a way i can restore my programs and settings through this folder or is it useless?

Comment: Which folder did you backup? Your home directory is in `/home/username` (not /usr as you seem to be suggesting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your settings. Copy all your old data from the backup user folder to your new home (be sure you can view hidden files, CTRL+H), then log out and log in again.

Comment: just replacing the new usr folder with the old usr folder would do it?

Comment: +Detailer Yes, as long as you have the same Ubuntu version or higher, the same username and it was not messed up too much it will work. All user settings are stored in configuration files within your home folder. But this will not restore system-wide apps and settings, sorry...

Comment: can you be more specific , which settings would be restored?

Comment: Everything personal (like the launcher icons, appearance, animations, shortcuts, applications settings, browser data like history and extensions, etc...) but not system-wide (like the language for new users, drivers, tweaks, apps from the Software Centre, etc...).